# gcc cannot recognize the option --allow-multiple-definition

Tags: gcc, configuration, ld

I have `gcc 7.3.0` and `ld 2.30-slack15`.
On configuring a project `(GnuTLS v3.5.16)`, an error is always thrown.

Checking the `config.log`:

```
configure:5411: x86_64-slackware-linux-gcc -g -O3 -fPIC --allow-multiple-definitions conftest.c >&5
x86_64-slackware-linux-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--allow-multiple-definitions'; did you mean '-Wold-style-definition'?
```

The invocation command is as follows:

```
$ ../configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/man --infodir=/usr/info --disable-shared --enable-static --verbose --target=x86_64-slackware-linux --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=x86_64-slackware-linux LDFLAGS=--allow-multiple-definitions
```

Comment: This is a [linker option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dallow_002dmultiple_002ddefinition), so try again with `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition` (without the trailing 's').

Comment: @ssbssa why not make this an answer?